# Get three letter month and day from string date?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsdate

I have string date such like,

```
NSString * dateStr = @"2014-12-31";
```

I want to get month in three letter month such like **Des** *(from dateStr)* and day such like **31**

I tried about 2 hour but i can't get it properly..

My code is..

First convert string to date ;

```
NSString *dateStr = [[self.listOfEvents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"EventDate"];
NSDateFormatter *DTFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[DTFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *eventDate = [DTFormatter dateFromString:dateStr];
NSLog(@"eventDate - %@", eventDate);
```

And now convert date to string;

```
NSDateFormatter *currentDTFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[currentDTFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM"];
NSString *eventDateStr = [DTFormatter stringFromDate:eventDate];
NSLog(@"eventDateStr - %@", eventDateStr);
```

So, please suggest me where i was wrong here.

**EDITED :**

I got console output is

> eventDate - 2014-12-31 18:30:00 +0000
>   eventDateStr - 2014-12-31

Comment: what is result of `NSLog(@"%@", eventDate);` and  `NSLog(@"%@", eventDateStr);` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you are converting using old dateformatter that is *`DTFormatter`* you have to use **currentDTFormatter** in place of it.

Try with **`currentDTFormatter`** this formatter.

```
NSDateFormatter *currentDTFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[currentDTFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM"];
NSString *eventDateStr = [currentDTFormatter stringFromDate:eventDate];
NSLog(@"%@", eventDateStr);
```

Comment: Thanks i got it now.. :).

Comment: Beware that the format "MMM" does not always result in exactly 3 letters. It merely stands for "abbreviated" month. In most cases that means 3 letters (e.g. "Mar"), but for the German word for March MMM results in "März" (same for Juni and Juli).

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this line `[currentDTFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];` before you are calling `setDateFormat`

Here is the appropriate passage from apple's documentation:

```
    NSDateFormatterMediumStyle

    Specifies a medium style, typically with abbreviated text, such as “Nov 23, 1937”.

    Equal to kCFDateFormatterMediumStyle.

    Available in OS X v10.4 and later.

    Declared in NSDateFormatter.h.
```

Answer (score 0):

It's also saying here https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1 to use just one "d" for the days so "EdMMM" should work for english locale or I guess "dMMM" even "d MMM"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-YYYY HH:mm"];
```

and then

```
[formatter stringFromDate:someNSDate];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Solution

```
NSString * dateStr = @"2014-12-31";
NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate* date = [df dateFromString:dateStr];
NSLog(@"%@", date);
[df setDateFormat:@"dd MMM"];
NSString *dateString = [df stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%@", dateString);
```

Try out

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use the below code to convert your date string...

```
- (NSString*) formatDateString:(NSString*)date
{
NSDateFormatter *inputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[inputFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

NSDate *formattedDate = [inputFormatter dateFromString: date];
NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM"];

NSString *displayDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [outputFormatter stringFromDate:formattedDate]];

return displayDate;
```

}

And also you can set format styles to `NSDateFormatter` for formatting your date string

```
setTimeStyle:
```

`setDateStyle:`

You can check `NSDateFormatter` for your reference from below link.

```
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html
```